# Shop By Brand call landing page category on right sidebar

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I am trying it countless hours.But no luck .
I Am using Shop by brand extension. i want to show current brands category at right sidebar there is called a **view.phtml** and its showing category  by this file.
.
**app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/shopbybrand.xml** .

```
 <shopbybrand_index_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="shopbybrand/view" name="shopbybrand_view" before="-" template="shopbybrand/view.phtml" />                                    
        </reference>
          </shopbybrand_index_view>
```

Now i am calling this file by different file name. Here Code

```
<shopbybrand_index_view>
            <reference name="right">
             <block type="shopbybrand/view" name="shopbybrand_view" before="-" template="shopbybrand/listingcategory.phtml" />                                    
        </reference>
          </shopbybrand_index_view>
```

Pleas help me how can I do it thanks in advance ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove before="-" from the code or change it to after="-"

Also note: `name="shopbybrand_view"` should be something else like: `name="shopbybrand_view_listingcategory"` for example.